# University club executive committee

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-process, cv

As a Mathematics student or a student in general wishing to go into research in the future, does being a member of the executive committee for the relevant club matter that much in terms of gaining positions in the future in research?

I have generalised anxiety disorder, and as a result I find it extremely difficult to join such clubs, and some of my fellow students who are on my level are gaining these positions with ease. Will this give them a large edge over me in the future?

Comment: hard to say. However, building a network is important. So try (I know easier said...) to interact with people socially! It will help you down the road!

Answer (score 2):

Personal reaction: It matters -- it's a chance to develop and demonstrate leadership skills -- but it's a low-level effect. Election is something of a crapshoot anyway; not all good candidates get elected. It's more important as worthwhile experience than anything else. If you can't or don't, that's OK; if you can it may be good for you.